# Symfony: turn off i18n on forms

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I would like to turn off i18n calls on some forms or even form widgets to enhance performance. Is this possible?

Comment: i18n for what ? Your contents ? The form labels / errors ? Is the i18n needed in your application or not at all ?

Comment: On content. Some form widgets like multiple choise, generate too many __() calls, which is inefficient and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the choices form widget, you can turn off auto translation by adding the option "translate_choices" set to false.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Though, sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice seems to ignore this option.